# lexical analyzer in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, lexical-analysis

hello guys im very new in programming scheme so im trying to build a lexical analyzer in scheme that basically reads a list for example `< SUM + 34 >` and the out put would be something like this

```
{ is the left bracket 
SUM is an identifier
+ is the plus operator
34 is a Digit
} is the right bracket
```

I'm using dr.scheme 
and the program does not exactly tell me what I am missing or hints of my mistakes.
 Everything is very new for me

This is what I have tried so far:

```
(define alist'( < SUM + 34 >))

(define (token? object)
  (and (list? object)
       (not (null? object))
       (eq? (car object) 'token)))

(define (ident-token? token)
  (type-token? token 'IDENTIFIER))
(define (digit-token? token)
  (type-token? token 'DIGIT))
(define (op-token? token)
  type-token? token 'OPERATOR)

(define (type-token? token type)
  (and(type-token? token)
      (eq? (name-token token) type)))

(define (name-token token)
  (cadr token))

(define (value-token token)
  (caddr token))

(define (spot-token)
  (cadddr token))

(define (assign-token name value spot)
  (list 'token name value spot))

(define *peek* '())

(define (check-token alist)
  (let ((token (if (null? *peek*)
                   (<token> in)
                   *peek)))
    (set! *peek* '())
    token))

(define (peek-token alist)
  (let ((token (if (null? *peek*)
                   (read-token in)
                   *peek*)))
    (set! *peek* (if token token '()))
    token))

(define (<token> alist)
  (let* (next-loc (next-spot in)) (next-char (peek-char in))
    (cond ((eof-object? next-char) #f)
          ((char-whitespace? next-char)
           (begin (check-char in)
                  (<token> in)))
          ((char-ident-initial? next-char)
           (<identifier> (list (check-char in)) next-loc in))
          (else
           (let ((next-char (check-char in)))
             (cond ((char=? #\( next-char)
                    (assign-token 'LEFT-PAREN "(" next-loc))
                   ((char=? #\) next-char)
                    (assign-token 'RIGHT-PAREN ")" next-loc))
                   ((char=? #\` next-char)
                    (assign-token 'ADD-OP "+" next-loc))
                   ((char=? #\] next-char)
                    (assign-token 'SUB-OP "-" next-loc))
                   ((char=? #\{ next-char)
                    (assign-token 'MULT-OP "*" next-loc))
                   ((char=? #\} next-char)
                    (assign-token 'DIV-OP "/" next-loc))
                   (else
                    (syntax-error next-loc next-char))))))))
```

Please guys I'm trying my best and nothing I try compiles. I have googled many things, but I couldn't find what could help me so..
even if you have tutorials or guides that would help me please share

Comment: Please indent the code before submitting. In DrRacket press ctrl+I .

Comment: missing set of parens on op-token and spacing is off on alist

Comment: You can check my just-for-fun project https://github.com/rmrfchik/jc It contains parsers which are compatible among schemes. I did it easy to use (at least tried to do so ;)

Comment: I would suggest to use silex instead of writing an own lexer: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~dube/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a little guidance in reading the error messages.

When I run your program above in DrRacket, I get the error:

```
expand: unbound identifier in module in: token
```

At the same time `token` in this functions is colored red:

```
(define (spot-token)  
  (cadddr token))     ; <---
```

This means that the compiler hasn't seen the name `token` before.

Now since you didn't include descriptions of purpose for your functions,
my guess is, that you forgot to use token in the list of arguments:

```
(define (spot-token token)   
  (cadddr token))
```

It is important to catch mistakes as early as possible.
My advice is each time you write a new function, write at
least one to two tests of the function before beginning 
with the next function.